# Looking for a package for finite mappings

Tags: packages, reference-request, sets

I am looking for a package for dealing with "mappings" $f\colon A\to B$ where $A$ and $B$ are finite subsets of the set of all possible (inert) expressions.

I need operations like:

- Computing $f(a)$ efficiently.
- Converting $f$ from and to a list of rules.
- Checking whether $f$ is injective (thus bijective).
- Computing the inverse function if possible.
- Listing the elements of $A$ and the set $f(A)$
- Ensuring or enforcing that the elements of $A$ and/or $B$ match a certain pattern, e.g. `_Integer`.
- Converting to and from a `List` for the case that $A$ is `Range[1, n]`.
- Efficient handling of the case that $B$ is a list of `MachineReal`s (`PackedArray`...).

I want this for the following purposes (not exhaustive):

- Abstract away different ways of representing variable-value assignments
- Abstract away differences between lists, matrices, tensors, SparseArrays, PackedArrays which can be understood as a mapping position $\to$ number.

Is there something out there that does this or could be extended easily or would you sit down the few hours it takes and program this from scratch? Am I missing some available functionality that provides a nice representation and implementation of such mappings?

Comment: `Association` will do some of the tasks you list, and it is generally efficient. `Map` will compose two of them. `PositionIndex` will get you part way to an inverse function & injectivity (not sure about efficiency). `Normal`, `Keys`, `Values` make various lists (rules, domain, range, resp.). But no built-in pattern checking, AFAIK. And you would have to build your own data structure on top it, if you want to carry along the codomain.