# Looking for a package for data on (sparse) uniform grids

Tags: packages, sparse-arrays, data-structures, reference-request, packed-arrays

I have large amounts of sparse 2d and 3d "volumetric" data, i.e. fixed data associated with positions in a uniform (integer coordinate) grid. I think of it as partial function

$$f: \mathbb Z^n \to D.$$

The data defined for each point has always the same structure - it's usually a list of numbers, or a matrix or another (nested) 3d grid of data. Ideally, I could store an arbitrary but fixed-format expression on each point.

I need operations such as the following:

- Accessing individual elements efficiently
- Accessing all elements in a neighborhood
- Applying operations to individual elements and neighborhoods, including convolutions and more general filters
- Constructing a grid with only a rearranged sublist of the current data on each point (e.g. for rearranging and pre-alpha-multiplying the color channels in an image, I would map the data `{r,g,b,a}` on each point to say `a*{b,g,r}`)
- Dropping points which match certain criteria.
- Listing all indices for which data is defined.
- Converting this data structure to other representations for interoperability and visualization

I would like to abstract-away the different ways of representing such data (I could think of using `Image`, `Image3D`, an array/tensor (an expression), a `SparseArray`, an `Association`, other ways to represent [finite mappings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121776/looking-for-a-package-for-finite-mappings), etc) and focus on the operations.

Has somebody already done this or seen a project that uses something like that?